# Add new button not working for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have a very strange situation: I created a CPT (WP 4.7) and i was even able to create one custom post. However, the Add New button stopped working and simply will go to the home page. That only happens with this new CPT as the others are working correctly.

Here's the code i used:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_recipes' );
    function create_recipes() { 
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Recipes',
        'singular_name'      => 'Recipe',
        'menu_name'          => 'Recipe',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Recipe',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Recipe',
        'new_item'           => 'New Recipe',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Recipe',
        'view_item'          => 'View Recipe',
        'all_items'          => 'All Recipes',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Recipes',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Recipes:',
        'not_found'          => 'No recipes found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No recipes found in Trash.'
    );

$args = array( 
    'public'             => true, 
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => 'Create your own recipes',
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-carrot',
    'rewrite'            => true,
    'menu_position'      => 4,
    'supports'           => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail')
);
register_post_type( 'recipe', $args );
}
```

As usual any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: yeap, i don't remember how, but it think what i did was recreate the CPT and that was it...or something like it